# Binomial series

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck in a problem about binomial series and would be very happy if someone could help me how to move on with it...

I have to prove that $\sum_{v=k}^{\infty }\binom{v}{k}z^{v-k}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}$ for $k\geq 0$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and  $\left | z \right |<1$.

Is this like the special case of binomial series $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{\beta +1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\binom{k+\beta}{k}z^{k}$ (according to Wikipedia), where i need to substitute $x=-z$ in the usual formula $(1+x)^{\alpha }=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\binom{\alpha }{k}x^{k}$ ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\sum_{v=k}^{\infty }{\binom{v}{k}z^{v-k}}=\sum_{u=0}^{\infty }{\binom{u+k}{k}z^u}$ where $u=v-k$. Do you see how to continue from here?

Comment: Your last expression is $\sum_{k=0}^\alpha$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, replace $(z,\beta,k)$ in WP formula by $(z,k,v-k)$ in the formula you want to prove and use the identity ${v\choose v-k}={v\choose k}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_kz^k$ for all $|z|<1$ then $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_k(z^k)' \ \forall \ |z|<1$; see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Analytic_functions).

Show that $\dfrac{1}{(k+1)(v-k-1)}\binom{v}{k}=\binom{v}{k+1}$ and use induction.